# Connection alive to a removed pod on k8s

Tags: java, sockets, kubernetes, networking, connection

We repeatedly have a situation that a client pod (http, zeromq) doesn't notice a server pod was restarted and somehow keeps the connection to the removed server pod, instead of reconnecting to the new one.

Restarting client pod helps of course, but this is rather a workaround.

Is there any explanation why does it happen and how to properly handle it?

Comment: TCP has no mechanism to detect loss of a network path; in fact TCP is specifically designed so that connections can survive loss of a network path.  The only reliable way for your client to detect that it can't talk to the other end is to try and send something to the other end.

Comment: Http Client does try to send requests and runs in timeouts. ZeroMq one has also built-in reconnect so in theory everything should work. But it doesn't on k8s

Comment: You haven't specified how exactly your client pod connects to server pod. Is it done using Service? Maybe headless service? Are you using a StatefulSet with predictable names and using that? What does "keeps the connection" means in this case?

Comment: Hi @g6380647 as `Andrew` asked can you provide the cluster's network configuration details or how you are mapping the client and server..?

Comment: We do it via service names:
client.url=http://servicename.namespace:8080
or for zeromq:
client.url=tcp://servicename.namespace:3033 . No stateful sets in this case